# How to assign a value to a variable in a class from JSON or pass this value to the next function?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, cs50

**Hi everyone!**
At the moment, I am taking a course at the Harvard computer science CS50.
My homework is almost ready, but has some incompleteness.
I cannot assign a value from a function to a variable in the class or pass
this value to the next function.

import UIKit

class PokemonViewController: UIViewController {

```
var url:    String!
var name:   String!

@IBOutlet var pokemonImage:     UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var nameLabel:        UILabel!
@IBOutlet var numberLabel:      UILabel!
@IBOutlet var type1Label:       UILabel!
@IBOutlet var type2Label:       UILabel!
@IBOutlet var catchButton:      UIButton!
@IBOutlet var descriptionLabel: UILabel!

// MARK: - additional properties
var currentDescURL: String!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    loadPokemon()
    
    showPokemonDescription()
}

//MARK: - pokemon loading
func loadPokemon() {
    guard let pokemonURL = URL(string: url) else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: pokemonURL) { (data, _, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(PokemonResult.self, from: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.navigationItem.title = self.capitalize(text: result.name)
                self.nameLabel.text = self.capitalize(text: result.name)
                self.numberLabel.text = String(format: "#%03d", result.id)
                
                for typeEntry in result.types {
                    if typeEntry.slot == 1 {
                        self.type1Label.text = typeEntry.type.name
                    }
                    else if typeEntry.slot == 2 {
                        self.type2Label.text = typeEntry.type.name
                    }
                }
                // Create Image and Update ImageView
                guard let imageURL = URL(string: result.sprites.front_default) else { return }
                if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imageURL) {
                    self.pokemonImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
                }
                self.currentDescURL = result.species.url
                print(self.currentDescURL)
            }
        } catch let error { print(error) }
    }.resume()
}

// MARK: - Get the URL of a specific Pokémon
func showPokemonDescription() {
    guard let pokemonDescriptionURL = URL(string: currentDescURL) else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: pokemonDescriptionURL) { (data, _, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(PokemonDescription.self, from: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // Check and get first pokemon description in English
                for index in 0..<result.flavor_text_entries.count {
                    if result.flavor_text_entries[index].language.name == "en" {
                        self.descriptionLabel.text = result.flavor_text_entries[index].flavor_text
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch let error { print(error) }
    }.resume()
}
```

}

The first function loadPokemon() inside itself gets value from JSON and prints the value to the console -> print(self.currentDescURL). Moreover, if you display this value in viewWillAppear, then "nil" will be displayed in the console. I understand that the loadPokemon() function processes the values in the stream that occur at the very end. Perhaps because of this, the variable currentDescURL cannot get the value from the loadPokemon() function and the showPokemonDescription() function cannot use this value since currentDescURL is nil.

I ask you to explain to me what my mistake is and to help finish the assignment.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How to assign a value to a variable currentDescURL?
This value I get inside the function loadPokemon(), but can't use in function showPokemonDescription().

Comment: My guess is that loadPokemon() is not yet done when you call showPokemonDescription().

Comment: I cannot assign a URL value from a function to a variable and use this value in the next function.
This value is stored in the function loadPokemon() and for some reason cannot be assigned to a var currentDescURL.
guard let pokemonDescriptionURL = URL(string: currentDescURL) -> it has no value because var currentDescURL is equal nil.

Comment: No need to repeat the question. I already gave you the reason and it is also addressed in the answer below. Please educate yourself about async programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the call for method `showPokemonDescription` from `viewWillAppear` to `loadPokemon` after the `currentDescURL` property is set.

```
class PokemonViewController: UIViewController {
    //...
    var currentDescURL: String!
    //...
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        loadPokemon()
        getPreferences()
        // <- remove the call from here
    }
    //...
    func loadPokemon() {
        //...
        self.currentDescURL = result.species.url
        self.showPokemonDescription() // <- move the call here
    }
    //...
    func showPokemonDescription() {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome! Lol, keep coding and with enough practise you'll get to know what to do in the future.